# TensorFlow 2.0 : How to control the name of a saved model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

On the TensorFlow 2.0 documentation page, the syntax to [save and load models](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) doesn't contain a `model name` argument.

I just saved a trained model on my local machine, but I couldn't change its `name` . It was automatically saved as `saved_model.pb`.

How can I control models' name?

Comment: Why do you need to change the model name ?

Comment: Let's assume that I want to train multiple models, and store them in a given folder. I want to control the name of each file I generate, so that I can load and use the right one whenever I want.